# Why when gcc is built from source, libstdc++ is built for wrong architecture, 32bit, while 64 is expected?

Tags: gcc, libstdc++

I am trying to compile lftp from source using gcc, compiler that I have also compiled from source under my home folder.
On build step I get an error:

```
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent  --tag=CXX   --mode=link g++  -O2 -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Woverloaded-virtual -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-implement-inlines -export-dynamic -s -o lftp lftp-lftp.o lftp-complete.o lftp-lftp_rl.o lftp-attach.o liblftp-jobs.la liblftp-tasks.la -L/usr/lib -lreadline -lutil -lncurses -ldl 
/gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/lib/../lib/libstdc++.so: error      adding symbols: File in wrong format
```

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [lftp] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/gsa/pokgsa-h3/19/leonidt/local/lftp-4.8.4/src'
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/gsa/pokgsa-h3/19/leonidt/local/lftp-4.8.4'
make: *** [install] Error 2

So looks like **compiler was built with libstdc++.so for wrong architecture?**

I tried to check what's in libstdc++.so:

```
file /gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/lib/libstdc++.so
/gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/lib/libstdc++.so: symbolic link to `libstdc++.so.6.0.27'

file /gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.27                    
/gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.27: **ELF 32-bit** MSB shared object, IBM S/390, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

Below are the steps I did to build gcc in my local folder:

```
 cd ~/local
```

Uncompressed the gcc-9.2.0.tar.xz
got ~/local/gcc-9.2.0 created with gcc source

```
cd ../gcc-9.2.0/
```

Downloaded prerequisites

contrib/download_prerequisites

cd ~/local/gcc-build

../gcc-9.2.0/configure --prefix /gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/ --enable-languages=c,c++

I am on SuSe Linux:

```
uname -a
```

Linux zdsdeveng03 3.0.101-108.84-default #1 SMP Fri Nov 30 15:57:27 UTC 2018 (7a72692) s390x s390x s390x GNU/Linux

```
cat /etc/os-release                                                                                     NAME="SLES"           
VERSION="11.4"
VERSION_ID="11.4"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP4"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:11:4"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify architecture(s) for configure script.

https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html

Comment: Thank you, Swift. I have close to no experience in the subject, would appreciate you pointing specific option to use. Meanwhile I am going to try: ../gcc-9.2.0/configure --prefix /gsa/pokgsa/home/l/e/leonidt/local/ --enable-languages=c,c++   **--with-arch-64=cpu**

Comment: @Leonid Tepliakov it depends what purpose you have for that build and whether your ssystem requres something else. That way it would support only x64 and work as native compiler , I think

Comment: Thank you, Swift. Looks that is exactly what I need.

Comment: make failed :(
checking if mkdir takes one argument... (cached) no
This target does not support --with-arch_64.
Valid --with options are: arch mode tune
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/gsa/pokgsa-h3/19/leonidt/local/gcc-build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/gsa/pokgsa-h3/19/leonidt/local/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
Any advice?

Comment: trying --with-cpu-64=cpu

Comment: same problem: 
checking if mkdir takes one argument... (cached) no
**This target does not support --with-cpu_64.**
Valid --with options are: arch mode tune
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/gsa/pokgsa-h3/19/leonidt/local/gcc-build'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/gsa/pokgsa-h3/19/leonidt/local/gcc-build'
make: *** [all] Error 2